# How to fix grub after moving root partition?

Tags: linux, debian, grub

Because I am using one of the new WD disks I am trying to aling my root partition with the real sectors, as described here:

http://community.wdc.com/t5/Desktop/Problem-with-WD-Advanced-Format-drive-in-LINUX-WD15EARS/m-p/10920#M631

So I copied all files to a temp location, deleted my partition (/dev/sda3), recreated it a few cylinders later (same name) and copied the files to the newly created partition. But now when I try to boot, I get my old grub menu but after selecting my kernel version it hangs... Any idea how I can fix it?

Comment: It just hangs with no error message?

Comment: The only error message I get is "Loading Linux 2.6.32-trunk-686 ...", no error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed now - the problem was that the partitions UUID has changed as an effect of my actions so I had to update /boot/grub/grub.cfg with the new ids, which I got by running (as root):

```
blkid
```