# How to make a copy of my / filesystem bootable

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, backup, grub

I have a 2TB SSD in my laptop, and 12 partitions on it, 6 of which are intended to hold versions of my root Xubuntu filesystem (as major updates happen).  I've been booting from nvme0n1p7, and I booted from a USB stick to copy it to nvme0n1p8.  I made a change to /etc/hostname, and to the entry for "/" in /etc/fstab.  I also changed the new filesystem's UUID.  I rebooted to the original partition and did "update-grub", which recognized the new partition.

However, all attempts to boot into the new partition seem to work, but only seem, because the hostname is not changed and blkid reports that "/" is on the original partition.  The culprit seems to be GRUB, because when I use its editor during boot, I see the entry for the new partition has the old UUID in the "root=" part.  Oddly, it has the new UUID in the "search" commands.  I don't understand the grub.cfg file that generates this, so I'm hesitant to edit it, and anyway it would probably go bad again on the next grub update.

I see a similar question at [Cloned Linux Mint Root parition to a new disk - won't boot](https://superuser.com/questions/1042414) but it has no answers at all, and the comments don't help me.

So the question is: what can I change that will make update-grub create the right configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I might be completely mistaken but there is a answer in the subject [How to fix grub after moving root partition?](https://superuser.com/questions/141606)

Screenshot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImrHy.png

I hope it will help.

Comment: should be a comment, link only answers are not good here at SU.

Comment: I have not enough reputation sorry I didn't know

Comment: It suggests editing grub.cfg.  I don't know what it looked like then, but now it is a tangle I don't understand and don't want to fool with.  I ran grub-update, which scans the disk, and I hoped would fix the UUIDs.  It didn't.  Besides, the text of the file says to not edit it.

Comment: @4Dummies You could make [a backup of all your partition](https://www.easeus.com/backup-utility/backup-drive-and-partition.html), and then edit grub.cfg I think It's worth trying.

Comment: #ayein That seems a bad idea for two reasons: 1) The file itself says to not edit it.  2) It is not at all obvious what to edit or why.  Without explicit information about what to change, and the reasons why it's a good idea, I'm going to ignore this advice.